# how to move backward and forward among android activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an application in which I'm supposed to make the user move backward to the last activity and to forward to the activities he left before using previous and next buttons?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the previous and next button?

Comment: I have a listview when the user clicks on any item of it a new activity is opened what I need is when the user presses back button he goes back :) to the list but when he presses the next button he goes to the item he selected or actually I want to put every activity he goes to in the stack history and I want to control that and not only for the listview activity for the other activities as well

Comment: See answers. When you click back you'll go back automatically. When clicking next all you need to do is maintain a reference to the currently/previously selected list item. You could even get the result of where you were from onActivityResult but then again you know that already. There's various ways of doing it.

Comment: @PJL:I actually stopped working on this program nowadays as I'm busy doing something else when I get back to it I'll post the way I'll use to solve this problem.Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough although the answers you have been given answer the question.

Comment: @PJL:I did it using onActivityResult. But for experience could you give me references or tutorials to know the other ways to do it. As I think that startActivity is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Have previous button end the current activity using `finish()` and next button fires of the activity. The layout for each of the activities having the same button bar.

In fact if your activities are fairly similar, for example just displaying different information say as you progress through them, you could get away with having the same activity and just calling it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
previousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {
             finish();
         }
     });         


nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
             startActivity(loginIntent);
         }
     });
```